# File permissions when mixing command line and server

Tags: bash, permissions, php

I have a PHP server which creates folders and files for certain things. I also run supporting code from the command line operating on the same folders and files.

The problem is that when running from the server, the file permissions for new files become `rwxr-xr-x _www _www`, whereas files created from the command line become `rwxr-xr-x user _www`.

So if I am on the command line as "user" and run PHP code which tries to delete files created from the server, I have to `sudo`, because "user" does not have write access to the files.

What is the correct way to fix it so that both the server and command line have equal permissions to the files?

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide what you want to do.  If the server runs as `_www`, and you use the command line as `user`, then files created by the server will be owned by `_www` and files created on the command-line will be owned by `user`.

You can change the ownership of files, but you need sudo for that too; even `_www` could not "give" a file to  `user`.

Your best bet is probably to put `user` in the `_www` group:

```
sudo usermod -a G _www user
```

And then set your server up so that it creates files giving write permission to the group as well as to the owner -- rwxrwxr_x instead of rwxr_xr_x.  `user` will then be able to delete those files.

Comment: Except the OP's file listing shows that group _www has only read and execute issues, maybe the webserver needs it's `umask` setting too.